# php mysql pdo connection not closing without destroying statement handler

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I want to explicitly close mysql connection in my php script to prevent too many connections, using below code:

```
<?php
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=HOST;dbname=DB',USER,PASSWORD);
$sth=$db->query("SHOW TABLES");
$sth=null;
$db = null;
sleep(10);
?>
```

Without adding **$sth=null;** in the above code, I am not able to close my mysql connection.

As stated in PDO document,

> To close the connection, you need to destroy the object by ensuring
>   that all remaining references to it are deleted

To ensure above, by assigning NULL to the variable that holds the object should ideally close my connection. but for the same, I need to destroy pdo statement handler references also.

In my code, I can make null all references of PDO object but to destroy statement handler in the large codebase is very difficult task for me. Any workaround?

Comment: Is this script running for a long time…? If not, there's little need to close the connection explicitly, since it's going to be discarded when the script ends anyway.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PDO closing connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18277233/pdo-closing-connection)

Comment: I have certain synchronous activities which take time, resulting in  making the connections on sleep. I need to close the connection before those activities

Comment: The third example of the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php#example-1013) anwsers to your question.

Comment: @YourCommonSense, It was different question yesterday. I was debugging the same problem though. I am still not able to see connection quit on mysql logs writing that particular code.

Comment: How it's any different?

Comment: @AnthonyB, Its not duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18277233/pdo-closing-connection. My application can not manage persistent connection.

Comment: @TanuGupta The question seems to be the same, closing connection with PDO. Also in the answer he explains what says the documentation. He says that setting _null_ to the variable is the right thing to do. The link to the documentation that I've posted above says the same, setting _null_ to the variable and the statement closes the connection.

Comment: @YourCommonSense, In that code (Reference https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49236104/mysql-pdo-connection-is-not-closing), I am not using pdo statement handler. Connection is getting closed with that particular code. Its just that I am not able to see that in mysql logs. Though, I can see the connection closed in mysql processlist.

Comment: You *can* see the connection close in the process list, just no entry in the log…?

Comment: @AnthonyB, this is what am I saying, what is the workaround of the same? Destroying statement handler is a tedious task to do in a very large codebase. What is the alternative solution of closing pdo connection

Comment: @deceze, Please dont get confused, I am referring https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49236104/mysql-pdo-connection-is-not-closing above

Comment: Then please don't confuse us. ;-) I think I am starting to see your point though.

Comment: @TanuGupta a possible workaround would be to create a class that does the job. It would be a wrapper for PDO, that would have a method to destroy automatically the connection and the statement.